# MongoDB GridFS vs AWS S3 for File Storage for Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, amazon-s3, upload

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches to store and retrieve JSON data in Meteor?

Storing and retrieving are must be done in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

We used on our server GridFS for a while before switching to AWS-S3 a few weeks ago. I can't really say what went wrong back then but every once in a while, an uploaded file would cause some error on the server and crash it randomly, despite the fact we enforced size and mime limitations. Also, when trying to retrieve and visualise those files, the server would start screaming and some crashed while uploading files would just be pointing to thewebsite.url/uploaded-docs/null. There is this note on the README:

> NOTE: This package is under active development right now (2014-3-31).
>   It has bugs and the API may continue to change. Please help test it
>   and fix bugs, but don't use in production yet.

Because of that, we now use AWS and despite the fact it's not so free, we didn't encounter any other crash on file upload from our users. But as I said, the package note is pretty old and we couldn't really understand if the issue was on our end or on GridFS. I'd be interested if any other have some insights on this matter.